# Boxplot graph getting skew

Tags: r, boxplot, skew

I'm really new in R statistics and i just bumped into a problem when it comes to creating a box plot. I have used the following script that i have created:

```
    # Reset R's braingetwd
rm(list=ls())

# Tells R where to look
setwd("/Users/Axel/Desktop/Kandidatarbete/Data")
# Confirms R is looking at the right place
getwd()
# Read data
read.table("migration_test_graph.txt")

# Assign a name to the data
migrationtest5<- read.table("migration_test_graph.txt", ,col.names=c('treatment','migration'), header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="NA", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE)

mzmz=migrationtest5[which(migrationtest5$treatment == "MzMz"),]
mzct=migrationtest5[which(migrationtest5$treatment == "MzCt"),]
ctct=migrationtest5[which(migrationtest5$treatment == "CtCt"),]
ctmz=migrationtest5[which(migrationtest5$treatment == "CtMz"),]

#plot data (migration in function of index)
boxplot(migration~treatment, data=migrationtest5, boxwex=0.5, varwidth=TRUE, staplewex=FALSE, outline=TRUE, outpch=20, cex= 0.3, range=1, title=FALSE, whisklty=19, col=c("darkolivegreen","darkolivegreen","darkolivegreen3", "darkolivegreen3"), xlab="", ylab="Migration index", las=1, ylim=c(0, 1), cex.lab=1, cex.axis=0.75, axes=FALSE, border=NA, medcol="white", whiskcol="black", outcol="black", whisklwd=2, medlwd=4)
axis(1, at=seq(0, 5, by=1), cex.axis=1, labels=c("", "CtCt","MzCt", "CtMz", "MzMz",""), lwd=2)
axis(2, at=seq(0,1, by=0.2), las=2, cex.axis=1, lwd=2)
```

[image]

The problem is that the whole graph looks skew and the data are located on the wrong places. Anyone got a clue what might be the problem? The big box plots are supposed to be located above the CtMz and MzMz and the small ones above the MzCt and CtCt.

Thanks in advance

Axel

Comment: What is the result of `sapply(migrationtest5, class)`?

Comment: You mean i should run this script? I'm really new to this.

When i run the code you wrote it said:

> sapply(migrationtest5, class)
treatment migration 
 "factor" "numeric"

Comment: It was to check you are working with numerical data in "migration" column.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't seem to be the problem unfortunately

Comment: I have added a picture of the graph now that i got some more reputation.

Comment: can you try `axis(1, at=seq(1, 5, by=1), cex.axis=1, labels=c("", "CtCt","MzCt", "CtMz", "MzMz"), lwd=2)`. The boxplot function starts mostly at 1 not 0. Or delete the axes=FALSE command.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Had a blank space in the txt file that made the graph skew. I corrected the wrong data by adding a,b,c,d in front of the treatment names in the txt file so that R put them in order!

Thanks a bunch for the help, this forum is so fast and i will definitely use it again if i run into any problems!

Cheers :-)